# Selenium/Python: How do I grab all instances of a button that's within a class at the same level as another class?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

On this particular page, there are two occurrences of the span class="channel-name". Under each of these span classes on the same level, there are multiple instances of div class="contract ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle". And under each of these I'm trying to retrieve all of the button class text (i.e. B), the last line of the HTML code extract.

HTML Code:

```
<span class="channel-name">
<div class="contract ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" ng-repeat="contract in data.channel.contracts track by $index" drag-data="contract" mit-draggable="">
  <div class="ng-isolate-scope ui-droppable" ng-class="{'invisible': atMaxContractsPerChannel(data.channel)}" drop-success="addToContractTop" drop-data="{verticalSeq: $index, contract: contract, priority: data.priority}" mit-droppable="">
    <div class="drop-zone-placeholder"></div>
    <mit-contract class="ng-isolate-scope" data="{verticalSeq: $index, contract: contract, channel: data.channel, currentProgram: data.currentProgram, programBackup: data.programBackup}">
      <div class="ibox-content no-margins " tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-class="beacon-body-uib-tooltip" tooltip-append-to-body="true" uib-tooltip-template="ui.views.infoTooltip" tooltip-is-open="errorAndHovering" tooltip-trigger="none" mit-err="{errs:[{event:'contract_0-0', context:'validateProgram'}], errClass:'mit-err-right-border'}">
        <button class="name btn-link ng-binding ng-isolate-scope" tooltip-class="beacon-body-uib-tooltip" tooltip-placement="left" tooltip-append-to-body="true" uib-tooltip="Edit" ng-disabled="disableEdit()" mit-mini-modal="" ng-click="editContract(contract)">B</button>
```

My python code. All it does now is check the column name to make sure it's searching the right channel-name and if so to retrieve the first button name under it and return it, I know I'm going about it the wrong way, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
def get_contract_name_in_inuring_column(self, column_name):
        elements = self.page_loc.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='channel-name']")
        count = 0
        for element in elements:
            if element.find_elements_by_xpath(".//input[@name='name']")[0].get_attribute('value') == column_name:
                return self.page_loc.presence_of_all_css('button[ng-click="editContract(contract)"]')[count].text
            count += 1
```

Comment: **.//button[@class='name btn-link ng-binding ng-isolate-scope']**. Try this XPath using FindElements instead of FindElement. Store it in a List<WebElment>. Then iterate through the stored list and you can get the text. Hopefully it might work.

Comment: @Sudeepthi that unfortunately returns all of the button texts on the page, not the specific two buttons i'm after within the div class on the same level as the span class.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought only those 2 buttons have that class name. Let me try something else and come back.

Comment: **.//button[@class='name btn-link ng-binding ng-isolate-scope'][@tooltip-class='beacon-body-uib-tooltip']** can you try this.

Comment: If this doesn't work find the attributes that are unique to these 2 buttons. Is the text on the 2 buttons same and unique from the rest?

Comment: @Sudeepthi the html code block for the buttons are identical, the only difference is the text which is unique. i.e. B in this extract - `>B</button>`

Comment: **.//button[contains(.,'Text of the button here')]**

Comment: @Sudeepthi surely that's working in reverse right? I need to get a button text by searching every div class="contract ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" on the same level as the span class="channel-name"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109174/discussion-between-user4659009-and-sudeepthi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the First and second buttons, here is the XPath.

```
(.//button[@class='name btn-link ng-binding ng-isolate-scope'][@tooltip-class='beacon-body-uib-tooltip'])[1] 
(.//button[@class='name btn-link ng-binding ng-isolate-scope'][@tooltip-class='beacon-body-uib-tooltip'])[2]
```